# Visual Studio 2022: System.InvalidOperationException: "git" is not present in PATH

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to compile the following project:

```
https://github.com/xoofx/markdig
```

In Visual Studio 2022, How to resolve the error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "git" is not present in PATH.
```

**What's the correctly way to install 'git' for visual studio?** I thought Visual Studio Already has git installed out of the box, judging by the label "Git" on the menu bar.

Here's a picture of my screen:

[image]

Menu: Tools->Command-Line:

[image: Visual Studio 2022 CommandLine]

[image: git.exe under visual studio 2022]

Comment: I think this is not a visual studio problem. Can you please launch your command line and run the git command to check if it is there and reachable?

Comment: how to launch command line from visual studio?

Comment: Not in VS. If you are using windows, look at the task bar, there should be a lens icon with 'Type here to search' text appearing in it. Type in cmd, and hit enter.

Comment: ok... i just added it to the orignal question...  One thing i dont understand... doesn't Visual Studio come preinstalled with git?  Why wouldn't it be in the PATH automatically?

Comment: Git for Windows is a separate component (but not installed automatically) that can also be installed from the Visual Studio Installer - "Tools -> Get Tools and Features..." Select the Individual Components tab and type git in to the search field.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for adding the picture. You need to have git installed. This can be done independently or through visual studio installer.

https://git-scm.com/downloads

It will ask you during installation if you want it to be added to the path - choose yes.

Once you have installed, launch the command window from start menu

[image: You can launch command window from start menu]

and run git command. That should show something like this -

[2][image]

Once you have git command running from command line it should work from visual studio as well. Essentially VS is trying to launch that command from its shell and failing to find it because you dont have git installed.

VS does come with git installed but you have to choose it in its workloads. You have to go through all available installation options. See the screenshot below from VS 2017 installation workload. You can do this by re-launching your VS installer and selecting the products that you want installed. Since I use most of the things, I dont uncheck anything but that takes close to 50Gig space on the disk - something you want to be aware of.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried in Visual Studio 2022: Menu Tools->Get-Tools-And-Features,  Select Tab "individual components", In Search box type "git", select "Git For Windows", Click "Modify"

Comment: Thanks! I learned something as well..